# Why is React.js removing the srcset tag on <img />?

Tags: html, reactjs, srcset

When I have the `srcset` property on my `<img />` tag, why doesn't it show up in the browser? It appears as through React.js is stripping it out.

```html
<img src="/images/logo.png" srcset="/images/logo-1.5x.png 1.5x, /images/logo-2x.png 2x" />
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The solution is to use `srcSet` instead of `srcset`.

```html
<img src="/images/logo.png" srcSet="/images/logo-1.5x.png 1.5x, /images/logo-2x.png 2x" />
```

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html under `HTML Attributes`

Comment: how can this be a react solution? where is the import anyway? Can you really deploy with the above code?

Comment: In React, you have JSX. This allows you to write something similar to HTML, then Babel or any other transpiler uses a special React plugin to convert it to JavaScript. Yes, this can be used in production. No import needed.

Answer (score 8):

Another ugly solution using template literals:

```
<img
  alt=''
  src={require('../../assets/images/logo/logo.png')}
  srcSet={`
    ${require('../../assets/images/logo/logo@2x.png')} 2x, 
    ${require('../../assets/images/logo/logo@3x.png')} 3x
  `}
/>
```

Comment: You can make it pretty if you import the file in the top

Comment: @StephaneL Would that mean you're importing the images on every browser though?

Comment: @Sam no, Webpack resolves the imports of images (or require) as a string (the uri of the image). The image data will just be fetched when the browser requests it and the browser will decide which image it needs according to `srcSet`.

Answer (score 3):

Tried to use srcSet with a string didn't work for me probably because how Webpack works so in the end, imported them and include them with the template string as in the next example:

```
import nat1 from "./img/nat-1.jpg";
import nat1Large from "./img/nat-1-large.jpg";
import nat2 from "./img/nat-2.jpg";
import nat2Large from "./img/nat-2-large.jpg";
import nat3 from "./img/nat-3.jpg";
import nat3Large from "./img/nat-3-large.jpg";


  <div className="composition">
                <img
                  srcSet={`${nat1} 300w, ${nat1Large} 1000w`}
                  sizes="(max-width: 56.25em) 20vw, (max-width: 37.5em) 30vw, 300px"
                  alt="Photo 1"
                  className="composition__photo composition__photo--p1"
                  src={nat1Large}
                />
                <img
                  srcSet={`${nat2} 300w, ${nat2Large} 1000w`}
                  sizes="(max-width: 56.25em) 20vw, (max-width: 37.5em) 30vw, 300px"
                  alt="Photo 2"
                  className="composition__photo composition__photo--p2"
                  src={nat2Large}
                />
                <img
                  srcSet={`${nat3} 300w, ${nat3Large} 1000w`}
                  sizes="(max-width: 56.25em) 20vw, (max-width: 37.5em) 30vw, 300px"
                  alt="Photo 3"
                  className="composition__photo composition__photo--p3"
                  src={nat3Large}
                />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import meal1x from '../images/meal.jpg';
import meal2x from '../images/meal@2x.jpg';
import meal3x from '../images/meal@3x.jpg';


 <img
    className='meal'
    src={meal1x}
    srcSet={`${meal1x} 1x, ${meal2x} 2x, ${meal3x} 3x `}
  />
```