# picture tag in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to use **picture** Tag in react app (jsx file) but it doesn't seems to work.
Here is my code

```
 <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" src="image_Desktop.png"/>
      <source media="(max-width: 768px)" src="image_Mobile.png"/>
      <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)" src="image_Tab.png"/>
      <img src="image.png" alt="" styleName='brain-image'/>
 </picture>
```

I tried giving attribute as srcset/src both in source tag but still not working.Any solution for the above problem?

Comment: use srcset and make sure the image exist at the specified path, it should work.

Comment: Yes I used srcset as well but, still not working.

Comment: In chrome, open the developer tools and open the Network tab. Filter to see Img only. Check the source of the requested image - is it correct?

Comment: `<picture>
  <source srcSet={downloadMetamaskWEBP} type="image/webp" />
  <source srcSet={downloadMetamaskPNG} type="image/png" />
  <img src={downloadMetamaskPNG} alt="download metamask" />
 </picture>`

In React this always falls back to the png file, even if the browser support the new webP format.

What am I doing wrong?

@BlahBlah In the example above, did you get it to work or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using srcset instead of using srcSet (with capital), this could be your problem.

Here is the another problem caused by usage of srcset:

[Why is React.js removing the srcset tag on <img />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695899/why-is-react-js-removing-the-srcset-tag-on-img)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Official Doc :

> The HTML `<picture>` element is a container used to specify multiple
>    elements for a specific  contained in it. The browser
>   will choose the most suitable source according to the current layout
>   of the page (the constraints of the box the image will appear in) and
>   the device it will be displayed on (e.g. a normal or hiDPI device.

And img is a DOM element but a javascript expression.

Possibly duplicate of this [React img tag issue with url and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054512/react-img-tag-issue-with-url-and-class)

If this doesnt help you , please share the inspected HTML for this Component