# Property 'srcset' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can someone help with the TypeScript error:

```
Property 'srcset' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'.
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong. I also tried this solution, but no result:

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
      interface IntrinsicElements {
        srcset: React.DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695900/367865

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use `srcSet` instead of `srcset` -> [Why is React.js removing the srcset tag on <img />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695899/why-is-react-js-removing-the-srcset-tag-on-img/34695900#34695900)